# Converting time across timezones, while preserving DST + other adjustments, using bash/sh

Tags: bash, shell, date, sh

Given any two or more timezones, I would like to convert the local time in any timezone to any other such that the time representation accurately represents any local alterations (DST, etc) that each timezone has in effect.

Specifically, if some of the timezones I provide happen to deal with DST considerations, I need to detect and catch this such that the appropriate recalculations will automatically be made - for example, that the output for those timezones is automatically adjusted forward or backward by one hour.

I want to do all of this from the shell, if possible, preferably using portable techniques; I was considering handing off the heavy lifting to `date`, but I'm not sure how to have it perform relative timezone-accurate calculation, especially in a way that's crossplatform to at least Linux and BSD.

Comment: The `TZ` variable controls the timezone that `date` uses. Compare `date` to `TZ=CET date` or `TZ=Egypt date` (to pick some random zones).

Comment: That will actually work, for my simple use case!

Comment: I had a second problem, however, which initially eluded my efforts at articulation - I need to do this calculation on arbitrary times in the future... what if, 1 hour from now, DST kicks in in another timezone? I need that timezone to jump forward appropriately.

Comment: I think I've possibly solved it - `TZ='Europe/Kiev' date -d 'Oct 25 3:59+1 hour'` produces `Sun Oct 25 05:59:00 EET 2015`...!
:D

Comment: That was due to a parsing bug. I also think I've found some other bugs in `date` - `TZ='Europe/Kiev' date -d 'Oct 25 2:59AM'` returns `Sun Oct 25 02:59:00 EEST 2015`, and `TZ='Europe/Kiev' date -d 'Oct 25 3:00AM'` returns `Sun Oct 25 03:00:00 EET 2015`, **but** `TZ='Europe/Kiev' date -d 'Oct 25 2:59AM+1 hour'` returns `Sun Oct 25 03:59:00 EEST 2015`. You can see that it's not parsing relative DST crossing changes correctly!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to UTC first and then convert to the target time zone (using CET as an example)

```
TZ=CET date --date=@$(TZ=UTC date +%s)
```

DST will be taken automatically.

Comment: THIS CAN WORK! `export TZ='Europe/Kiev'; date --date=@"$(TZ=UTC date -d 'Oct 25 00:59' +%s)"; date --date=@"$(TZ=UTC date -d 'Oct 25 1:00' +%s)"` produces `Sun Oct 25 03:59:00 EEST 2015` then `Sun Oct 25 03:00:00 EET 2015`. Thanks. :D